# Running Python from parent directory yield ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.gcloud_image'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, environment

Here is what my file tree looks like

```
server
  classifiers
  __init__.py
    gcloud
      __init__.py
      identifier.py   
  config
    __init.py
    gcloud.image
```

I am getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError" when I run `python classifiers\gcloud\identifier.py` which has `import config.gcloud_image` from the server directory on PyCharm (Python 3.7) in Windows 10. Does Python checks for modules from where I am running or where the file is located?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Answer (score 0):

I believe running the following instead could help:

```
path\to\pythonX.Y -m classifiers.gcloud.identifier
```

Make sure the `classifiers\gcloud\identifier.py` file has a block such as the following:

```
def main():
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```